# Sequential rxjs call with parallel inner calls

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Using rxjs, I would like to make a group of http calls with the value returned from a previous call. I would like the inner calls to execute in parallel. I also need to return the value from the first call as soon as it is available. I need to be able to subscribe to the result and handle any errors. Errors produced by the inner calls should not cause sibling calls to cancel.

I have the following code that works, but waits to return the initial value until the inner calls are complete because of the use of `forkJoin`:

```
public create(customer: Customer, groupIds: number[]): Observerable<Customer> {
    const response = this.http.post<Customer>('/customer', customer).pipe(mergeMap(
        (created) => {
            return forkJoin([
                of(created),
                forkJoin(groupIds.map(groupId => {
                    const membership = new Membership(created.Id, groupId);
                    return this.http.post<Membership>('/membership', membership);
                )
            ]);
        }
    )).pipe(map(a => a[0]));

    return response;
}
```

Is there a way to return the created customer without waiting for the inner calls to complete? Barring that, is there a way to write the above code more concisely?

(Note: `this.http` is of type `HttpClient` from Angular, and returns an `Observable<T>`)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a local variable for the customer, you could do something like this:

```
public create(customer: Customer, groupIds: number[]): Observerable<Customer> {
    const response = this.http.post<Customer>('/customer', customer).pipe(
      tap(created => this.customer = created), // <---
      mergeMap((created) => {
            return forkJoin([
                of(created),
                forkJoin(groupIds.map(groupId => {
                    const membership = new Membership(created.Id, groupId);
                    return this.http.post<Membership>('/membership', membership);
                )
            ])
        }
    )).pipe(map(a => a[0]));

    return response;
}
```

Adding a tap before the mergeMap sets the customer to a local variable. That then gives you access to the created customer before the child operations complete.

I did a stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-create-todo-deborahk

(It uses todo/posts instead of customers/groups but it should be similar in concept.)

**Alternatively**

You could do something like this:

```
  private todoCreatedSubject = new BehaviorSubject<ToDo>(null);
  todoCreatedAction$ = this.todoCreatedSubject.asObservable();

  private groupSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number[]>([5, 10]);
  groupAction$ = this.groupSubject.asObservable();

  todo$ = this.todoCreatedAction$.pipe(
    mergeMap(todo =>
      this.http.post<ToDo>(this.todoUrl, todo, { headers: this.headers })
    )
  );

  posts$ = combineLatest([this.todo$, this.groupAction$]).pipe(
    switchMap(([created, groupIds]) =>
      forkJoin(
        groupIds.map(groupId => {
          const post = {
            userId: created.userId,
            title: "Post:" + groupId,
            body: created.title
          } as Post;
          return this.http
            .post<Post>(this.postUrl, post, { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(tap(post => console.log(post)));
        })
      )
    )
  );
```

It defines two separate streams. `todo$` would be similar to your customer and is then accessible immediately after it is posted.

`post$` would be similar to your memberships.

I also created a stackblitz for this one here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-create-declarative-todo-deborahk

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use the value from the parallel calls (as it's the case of your current code):

```js
public create(customer: Customer, groupIds: number[]): Observerable<Customer> {
  const response = this.http.post <Customer>('/customer', customer)
    .pipe(
      tap(() => groupIds.map(groupId => {
          const membership = new Membership(created.Id, groupId);
          return this.http.post <Membership>('/membership', membership).subscribe();
        ))
      }
    ));

  return response;
}
```

If you do need to use the data, you could use the `startWith` for the `forkJoin`

```js
public create(customer: Customer, groupIds: number[]): Observerable<Customer> {
    const response = this.http.post<Customer>('/customer', customer).pipe(mergeMap(
        (created) => {
            return forkJoin(groupIds.map(groupId => {
                    const membership = new Membership(created.Id, groupId);
                    return this.http.post<Membership>('/membership', membership);
            ).pipe(startWith(created);
        }
    ));

    return response;
}
```

Comment: I don't use the value from the parallel calls, but in your first example, `created.Id` is no longer valid as you're not capturing it anywhere.

Comment: With using tap in the first example instead of a higher-order mapping operator, what is subscribing to the inner observable?

Comment: Forgot to remove the pipe, answer got updated. I also included an empty subscribe since you don't care about the data from the parallel calls

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to build an Observable that

1. emits the customer as soon as it is fetched ("*I also need to return the value from the first call as soon as it is available*") but
2. uses the customer data to make a series of subsequent http calls, in parallel,  to save the memberships data and emit once all the memberships are saved (i.e. when all parallel http calls return)

If my understanding is right, I would proceed as follows.

First I would create a function that takes a `customerId` and an array of `groupIds` and return an Observable that implements the parallel calls using `forkJoin`, something like

```
function createMemberships(customerId: string, groupIds: number[]) {
  return forkJoin(groupIds.map(gId => 
    createMembershipHttpSimulation(customerId, gId))
  )
}
```

Then I would create a second function that returns the Observable you want, like this.

```
function create(customer: Customer, groupIds: number[]) {
  const createCustomerObs = createCustomerHttpSimulation(myCustomer).pipe(
      shareReplay(1)
  )
  const createMembershipsObs = createCustomerObs.pipe(
    concatMap(customer => createMemberships(customer.id, groupIds))
  )
  return concat(createCustomerObs, createMembershipsObs)
}
```

This function first creates the Observable `createCustomerObs` that invokes the remote API to create the Customer and makes sure its subscription is shared using `shareReplay(1)`. Then creates a second Observable, `createMembershipsObs`, that pipes `createCustomerObs` into the `forkJoin` required to fire the requests to create memberships in parallel. Finally it concatenates, via `concat`, `createCustomerObs` and `createMembershipsObs`. The result of this concatenation is another Observable which emits as soon as `createCustomerObs` emits and then emits when `createMembershipsObs` emits, i.e. when the parallel calls complete. The use of `shareReplay` makes sure that the Customer creation API is called only once.

[Here a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-wx2tkd?devtoolsheight=60) that shows this approach. I use some delays to show on the console that the Customer is emitted first and then come the Memberships